# Solr Edismax is not working for Query operation

Tags: solr

I am facing some challenges while working on **Solr** 6. I am using stopwords.txt file where I have defined "and" as one of the word. Then I have indexed all the documents and find that and is not getting indexed using Analysis option in **Solr** admin console.
Now I am trying to query the data using edismax. Here is the the details of the value that I am using:
**q: quantify and address revenue leakage
fl:raw_text,fileAbsolutePath
indent:on
edismax: true
qf:raw_text
pf:raw_text
stopwords:On
lowercaseOperators: off**

The query result returned is not proper as find the and the "q" parameter is getting used as logical AND operation which should not be the case.It should skip the word and as it is in the stopword.txt.

Comment: so, it retrieved docs which contains AND inside? or what?

Comment: No it is working as and operator just establish ing AND relationship between left and right string

Comment: aha, so it's treating like AND boolean and you want it to be treated as AND word

Comment: No I don't want to treat it as AND word and already I have added it to stopwords list. I just want to ignore the word AND which is not happening. it is working as logical AND.

Comment: Can you add the output of the debug. Also, try to simplify this use case to the minimum set of terms demonstrating the problem.